# JavaScript: Why does the "for in" loop pick variables from __proto__?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, prototype

I added a method `trigger` to the prototype of Object:

```
Object.prototype.trigger = function() {
    //  ...
    return this;
};
```

And then have a "for in" loop:

```
var obj = { 4: 15, 10 : 41, 11 : 46, 12 : 51, 20 : 74 }
for( item in obj ) {
    foo( obj[item] );
}
```

But this loop has 6 iterations instead of 5. The last iteration is with key:

```
item = "trigger"
```

Why is the loop iterating over the `__proto__` part of the object?

[image]

Comment: This is how for in was written. Use `hasOwnProperty` to check whether it is not a proto property

Comment: Put the wrong duplicate link. Anyway, `for..in` iterates **all** enumerable properties.

Comment: Good source for reading - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for..in` iterates over *all* enumerable properties anywhere on the prototype chain. If you want to make `trigger` non-enumerable so it isn't iterated over with `for..in`, use `Object.defineProperty` instead, which makes the defined property non-enumerable by default:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'trigger', { value:  function() {
    
}});
var obj = { 4: 15, 10 : 41 }
for( item in obj ) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure. I think you still should do a call to `Object.hasOwnProperty`, there could be other code extending the prototype.

Answer (score 4):

`for...in` goes over all of the object properties without distinguishing between properties on the object itself or any of its ancestors.

In order to go over only properties defined on the object itself, you can use `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`:

```js
const obj = { 4: 15, 10 : 41, 11 : 46, 12 : 51, 20 : 74 }
for( item in obj ) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(item) {
    foo( obj[item] );
  }
}

// will ignore the trigger func and everything else defined on any prototype
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do is to use Object.keys instead :

```js
Object.prototype.trigger = function() {
    return this;
};

var obj = { 4: 15, 10 : 41, 11 : 46, 12 : 51, 20 : 74 }

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(item) {
    console.log( "Key: " + item + ", value: " + obj[item] );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an error I faced with arrays some time ago. Because arrays are also objects and you could iterate down into the prototype, do not use `for..in` for the arrays. Your example is specific for an object that causes this issue. Instead, use standard `for` to iterate through the items of your object. That way you could have a cleaner and safer implementation for what you are trying to achieve, rather than using defineProperty or hasOwnProperty which are mostly used to implement reflection.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.values(obj).length; i++){
  console.log(i + ': ' + Object.values(obj)[i]);
  //foo( Object.values(obj)[i] );
}
```